# v-for show items that should be skipped in top level v-if

Tags: vue.js

I have got next code:

```
  <div v-for="question in questions">
      <h3 v-if="question.isEnabled">{{question.question}}</h3>
        <div v-for="answers in question.answers">
          <h4>{{answers.answer}}</h4>
        </div>
  </div>
```

It's should print only `question.isEnabled` question. In next iteration it should print answers from them. The problem that it's print even answers from question that not showing in `question.isEnabled` condition.

It's look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific problem is that `v-if` is a directive, so it has to be attached to an element and **only** affect that element. So your code is working as spected, because it shows, your `h3` element only when the condition is true.

For that case, you need to use a [`template v-if`](http://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#Template_v-if)

```
<div v-for="question in questions">
  <template v-if="question.isEnabled">
    <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>
      <div v-for="answers in question.answers">
        <h4>{{answers.answer}}</h4>
      </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `filterBy`

```
<div v-for="question in questions | filterBy true in isEnabled">
        <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>
        <div v-for="answers in question.answers">
           <h4>{{answers.answer}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: With your code I am getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`